# Question error (integral)

Tags: calculus, integration

Just wanna check is there any problem with the question 10 b. [image]

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong ?

Comment: "Just wanna check" $\rightarrow$ "I just wanted to check"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given x, you have to calculate the area of the circle of radius $y+1$ minus the circle of radius $1$ so the area is $\pi(y+1)^2-\pi\cdot1^2$

So your volume is:

$\int_0^1\pi(xe^x+1)^2-\pi dx=\frac{e^2+7}{4}\pi$

So the answer given is the correct one.